# Minimum spanning tree with weighted edges in the adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the following graph with weight on the edges:

[image]

With the following code

```
matrix = 
{{0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0},
{4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0},
{2, 1, 0, 8, 10, 0}, 
{0, 5, 8, 0, 2, 6},
{0, 0, 10, 2, 0, 2},
{0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 0}};
labels = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[labels, matrix /. {0 -> \[Infinity]}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Name" , ImagePadding -> 15];
SetProperty[g, EdgeLabels -> MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, 
  {EdgeList[g], PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]}]]
```

I'm trying to find the minimum spanning tree, but I don't know how to pass the weight of the edges to function since it's in an adjacency matrix. The function I'm using is FindSpanningTree.

```
FindSpanningTree[g, Method -> "Kruskal"]
```

Comment: Documentation for `FindSpanningTree` claims it handles weighted graphs. The result for this example certainly looks like it is giving a minimal total weight tree.

Comment: Check out [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igweightedadjacencygraph), which will save you the trouble of having to juggle zeros and infinities. It also has `IGSpanningTree`, should you want an independent verification for `FindSpanningTree`.